# How to safely save data to an existing file with C#?

Tags: c#, io

How do you safely save data to a file that already exists in C#? I have some data that is serialized to a file and I'm pretty sure is not a good idea to safe directly to the file because if anything goes wrong the file will get corrupted and the previous version will get lost.

So this is what I've been doing so far:

```
string tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();

using (Stream tempFileStream = File.Open(tempFile, FileMode.Truncate))
{
    SafeXmlSerializer xmlFormatter = new SafeXmlSerializer(typeof(Project));
    xmlFormatter.Serialize(tempFileStream, Project);
}

if (File.Exists(fileName)) File.Delete(fileName);
File.Move(tempFile, fileName);
if (File.Exists(tempFile)) File.Delete(tempFile);
```

The problem is that when I tried to save to a file that was in my [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com), sometimes I got an exception telling me that it cannot save to a file that already exists. Apparently the first `File.Delete(fileName);` didn't delete the file right away but after a little bit. So I got an exception in the `File.Move(tempFile, fileName);` because the file existed and then the file got erased and my file got lost.

I've used other applications with files in my Dropbox and somehow they manage to not mess it up. When I'm trying to save to a file in my Dropbox folder, sometimes I get a message telling me that the file is being used or stuff like that but I never had a problem with a file being erased.

So what would it be the standard / best practice here?

OK this is what I came up with after reading all answers:

```
private string GetTempFileName(string dir)
{
    string name = null;
    int attempts = 0;
    do
    {
        name = "temp_" + Player.Math.RandomDigits(10) + ".hsp";
        attempts++;
        if (attempts > 10) throw new Exception("Could not create temporary file.");
    }
    while (File.Exists(Path.Combine(dir, name)));

    return name;
}

private void SaveProject(string fileName)
{
    bool originalRenamed = false;
    string tempNewFile = null;
    string oldFileTempName = null;

    try
    {
        tempNewFile = GetTempFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName));

        using (Stream tempNewFileStream = File.Open(tempNewFile, FileMode.CreateNew))
        {
            SafeXmlSerializer xmlFormatter = new SafeXmlSerializer(typeof(Project));
            xmlFormatter.Serialize(tempNewFileStream, Project);
        }

        if (File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            oldFileTempName = GetTempFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName));
            File.Move(fileName, oldFileTempName);
            originalRenamed = true;
        }

        File.Move(tempNewFile, fileName);
        originalRenamed = false;

        CurrentProjectPath = fileName;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        if(tempNewFile != null) File.Delete(tempNewFile);

        if (originalRenamed) MessageBox.Show("'" + fileName + "'" +
            " have been corrupted or deleted in this operation.\n" +
            "A backup copy have been created at '" + oldFileTempName + "'");
        else if (oldFileTempName != null) File.Delete(oldFileTempName);
    }
}
```

`Player.Math.RandomDigits` is just a little function I made that creates an string with n random digits.

I don't see how could this mess up the original file unless the OS is going wacko. It's pretty close to Hans's answer except that I first save the file to a temporary file so that, if something goes wrong when serializing, I don't need to rename the file back to it's original name, which can also go wrong. Please! let me know if you find any flaw.

Comment: good question, i'm curious as to the answer.

Comment: Why not just do `File.Copy(tempFile, fileName, true);` followed by `File.Delete(tempFile);`?

Comment: @Mehrdad: I think that should do it. Wonder why no one posted it as an answer. If anything goes wrong with `File.Copy` I think the worst that can happen is that nothing happens and the original stays the same. Now, I can be wrong...

Comment: @jsoldi: You're assuming the data is written to the disk in an ordered fashion, which is a dangerous assumption that might happen to be true in some cases but not others. It could be that your request for all of these will complete, and then they will actually happen in a different order (to improve performance). You will then receive the same end result as before, but if anything goes wrong with the system itself (rather than just the application itself), you may not be able to guarantee crash recovery. That's why the transaction solution is best, if it's a critical operation.

Comment: It's not THAT critical. Is just a typical File -> Save operation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure how secure this is, but assuming your OS isn't crashing, guess what? There's an app for that: [File.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.replace.aspx)

```
File.Replace(tempFile, fileName, backupFileName);
```

---

I think what you *really* need in a critical situation is [transactions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb986748.aspx); only then can you guarantee against the loss of data. Take a look at [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163388.aspx) for a .NET solution, but be aware that it might be a bit harder to use than a simple file replacement solution.

Comment: I was considering this solution but the documentation says that it will raise an exception if it's on a different volume and I'm using `Path.GetTempFileName();` to create the temporary file which might be created on a different volume.

Comment: @jsoldi: Hm... why is your file on a different volume? Why not just save to the current volume?

Comment: Well the user might decide to save it to a USB which would be on a different volume than where the temporary file is created (see my code (I originally serialize to a file created with `Path.GetTempFileName();`)).

Comment: @jsoldi: Why not just write to a `MemoryStream` and then write that directly to the place you want, without having a temporary copy?

Comment: That's a possibility... I would still create a temporary copy of the original in case anything goes wrong in the middle of writing the file.

Comment: @jsoldi: No I mean, write it to a temporary file to the USB, then replace the original with it using `File.Replace`... does that not work?

Comment: Yea I was thinking about that... Let me think a little more ;)

Answer (score 4):

This is the way I usually do it:

1. Always write to a new file (say `hello.dat`) with an auto-increment serial number attached, or the time attached (just make sure that it is unique, so use ticks or microseconds etc.) -- say `hello.dat.012345`.  If that file exists, generate another number and try again.
2. After saving, forget about it.  Do other things.
3. Have a background process that keeps running through these new files.  If exists, do the following:
4. Rename the original file to a backup with a serial number or timestamp `hello.dat` -> `hello.dat.bak.023456`
5. Rename the last file to the original name `hello.dat`
6. Remove the backup file
7. Remove all intermediate files between the last file and the original file (they are all overwritten by the last file anyway).
8. Loop back to #3

If there is any failure anywhere between #3 and #8, send a warning message.  You're never losing any data, but temp files may build up.  Clean your directory once in a while.