# Can File.Copy copy from a volume to a different volume?

Tags: c#, io

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.IO.FILE.COPY%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) doesn't say anything about it and I don't have any way to test it right now. It does say it about [`File.Move`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.IO.FILE.MOVE%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) which makes me think `File.Copy` might not work across different volumes.

This is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386795/how-to-safely-save-data-to-an-existing-file-with-c) other problem I'm having.

Comment: I suppose possible some security issues, because it work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just tested it, it works. Just use:

```
File.Copy(@"C:\File.txt", @"E:\File.txt");
```

I agree it is weird this isn't mentioned in the documentation though.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason you can't copy a file across volumes. When performing a "move" operation, you're either doing a "rename" (when moving to the same volume) or "copy" then "delete" (when moving across volumes). Obviously a copy operation has to be able to work across volumes.

Note that the documentation you linked to for `File.Move` says:

> This method works across disk volumes

So I don't know what your issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it works.

Note that moving a file is a different operation than copying it. When you move a file inside its volume the OS just changes the pointer to that file, it doesn't have to read and write all data. Copying a file or moving it out of its volume does require that, and that is probably the cause of that comment.